# Grass doesn't grow

Tags: terraria

In terraria, ever since I changed into version 1.2.4, everytime I put dirt blocks (atempts to make artificial gardens), neither grass or vines grow. In other words, neither grow on artificialy-placed dirt blocks, even in different worlds :/
I want to know if this a Bug or if am I doing something wrong...

Comment: 1.2.4 or 1.2.4.1? (It worked for me on 1.2.4.1)

Comment: Grass spreads from other grass. It doesn't just grow from nowhere.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Druid sells grass seeds, if you can't get grass to grow automatically you can just buy alot of seeds from her

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Terraria isn't Minecraft. In Minecraft, if the dirt block is manually placed, no grass can grow on it.  However, Terraria is different.

As other users have commented, grass doesn't spread from just dirt.  It needs a surrounding grass tile for it to properly grow.

[image]

Comment: Grass *does* grow on manually placed dirt blocks in Minecraft, it just takes a while and the chunk needs to be loaded.

Comment: @JonK oh, because when I last played, manually placed dirt blocks did not grow grass, even with a grass block placed next to it

Answer (score 2):

To grow grass on dirst you need other patch of grass to be next to it, it will spread quickly over time. Contrary to Minecraft, you don't need sun and it won't appear if there's no grass nearby.

Note that grass can't appear below the surface lever. You may have notice that as you went deeper into the Underground, there's no grass on the dirt because there can't be grass, so make sure you're above the Underground.

If you want to create a garden you will want to:

- Create a temporary path of dirt to make the grass spread to your garden
- Use Grass Seeds you can buy to the Dryad for 20 Copper Coins.
- Use the Staff of Regrowth (which can be found in the Jungle), it has the same function as the Grass Seeds.

You may create an artificial garden in the Underground with the last two options but you won't be able to make a farm as no flowers, mushrooms nor trees will grow. (It will be purely aesthetic!)

The Dryad will spawn if these criterias are met:

> There is an empty House and you have killed one of the first bosses (Eye of Cthulhu, Eater of Worlds / Brain of Ctulhu or Skeletron).